# Return a substring AND remove leading zeroes in result using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, parsing

I have to return data in a certain way that has to be done entirely by the regex, no help from any other code.

Here is my input string which is a fixed position/length:

```
%O1TEST      00000500135800?
             ^start  ^end
```

I want to return the substring where it starts and ends above but I also want to remove any leading zeroes. The final result would be "5001".

If the substring was "123455001", it would return "123455001" (all 9 characters).

I have this so far: `.{13}(.{9})` which returns "000005001" but I can't figure out how to remove the leading zeroes as well.

Comment: Why did you ignored the part after `5001` ?

Comment: The part after 5001 is other data that I do not want. I only want the 9 characters starting at position 14 and ending at position 22.

Comment: what is the ultimate goal?  you need 5001 using only sql syntax?  do you need it as a string or as a number?  what database system?  could you combine a regex with other sql methods, like number parsing and type conversion?

Comment: The program that uses it is java. I have different properties that have different input strings. This is actually data encoded on a magstripe. So property A's data layout could be different from property B. In the java code, I get the regex string for the property from the DB and after the card is swiped, I use that regex string to extract the patron number which is a string. So the DB part is just a mechanism for storing different regex strings for different properties. I can't change the java code because that would require a reinstall everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, this will give you 5001 on match group 1:

```
'%O1TEST      00000500135800?'.match(/^.{13}0*(\d*).{6}$/)
```

this requires that you know the total string length.  the `^.{13}` matches the first 13 characters, the `.{6}$` matches the final 6 characters, `0*` eats up all the leading zeros and `(\d*)` matches any remaining numbers.

I might be able to provide you a better answer if you can answer my comment above about what you ultimately need and your language.  Not all regex flavors are created equal.

Comment: You did it! I'm sorry, but I should have worded my question better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your capturing group is taking all the characters from 14 to 22, so you have to limit it. The following regex should do the job, because it ignores the first 13 characters, then ignores any leading zeros and captures all the digits after any sequence of zeros and before the last five digits:

```
.{13}0*([0-9]+)[0-9]{5}
```

I don't know what you are trying, but this regex accepts any sequence of leading zeros, inclusive `00000000035800`, capturing just the last one. The result would be `0` in this case.

If you change the regex to:

```
.{13}0*([0-9]*)[0-9]{5}
```

It will also match the sequence `00000000035800` but an empty string will be returned by the capturing group.

Use the one that better accomplish to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure of the number of characters in the field you're matching [Mark Evaul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36186408/2642059) is a great one. If you're unsure of the number of digits this is fairly difficult.

Unfortunately the only thing that you can do with a a captured quantifier is recurse that many times on subsequent matches: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifier-capture.html And even then that's really just supported by advanced regex languages.

So you're stuck enumerating all possible combinations, thankfully there are just 10:

```
\s(?:([1-9]\d{8})|0([1-9]\d{7})|0{2}([1-9]\d{6})|0{3}([1-9]\d{5})|0{4}([1-9]\d{4})|0{5}([1-9]\d{3})|0{6}([1-9]\d{2})|0{7}([1-9]\d)|0{8}([1-9])|0{9}())
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/tP5zG3/1)

The space will ensure that that we match the match the number from the beginning. Each option is a total of 9 digits, with a varying number of leading 0s from 0 to 9.

This regex is capable of matching things like:

- `%O1TEST      00000500135800?`
- `%O1TEST     000000500135800?`
- `%O1TEST      000005001358000?`

Independent of the size of the number only the first 9 characters will be taken and leading zeros will be chopped from the match.